# Cannot achieve cross browser compatibility for js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, textarea

The code below works for disabling the backspace key in a textarea in Firefox perfectly but not Chrome or Safari, any suggestions would be very much appreciated

```
$('#texttype').keypress(function(event){ 
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '8'){ 
        return false;
    }
        event.stopPropagation();
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `e.which`, it's normalized in jQuery, and the keycode is an integer.

The `keydown` event triggers on any key press and gives a keycode in all browsers.

The `keypress` event triggers after `keydown` and does give a keycode, but it's only guaranteed for character keys, and does not fire on the backspace key in webkit.

```
$('#texttype').on('keydown', function(e) { 
    if ( e.which === 8 ) { 
        return false;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRWfG/1/)

Comment: It doesn't appear to work [when I test it](http://jsfiddle.net/d9VUC/) in Chrome.

Comment: I think that when I copy/pasted from your answer it said `keypress` not `keydown`. That makes a difference.

Comment: @Quentin - It did, and I quickly changed it, as keypress doesn't work with backspace in webkit

Comment: You should probably emphasise that instead of the use of `which` in your answer then :)

Comment: @Quentin - Just did :)